# How to make TextArea focus style same with non-focus style?

Tags: java, css, javafx

Here is my code:

```
.text-area {
    -fx-focus-color: transparent;
    -fx-faint-focus-color: transparent;
}
```

The screenshot is following(I focus  thefirst `TextArea`)

[image]

I have the following questions:

- the focused `TextArea` top has gray bar: how to remove it?
- the focused border color is white, how to make it like non-focus border color?
- the non-focused `TextArea` has border shadow, how to remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following CSS classes make `TextArea`s look the same both in focused and not focused state: simple white background, default border without shadow, no "gray" bar on top, no focus highlighting.

```
.text-area {
    -fx-focus-color: transparent;
    -fx-faint-focus-color: transparent;
}

.text-area .content {
    -fx-background-color:-fx-control-inner-background;
}
.text-area:focused .content {
    -fx-background-color:-fx-control-inner-background;
}

.text-area:focused {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom, derive(-fx-text-box-border, -10%), -fx-text-box-border), -fx-control-inner-background;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1;
    -fx-background-radius: 3, 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and change the color to the one you want

```
.text-area:focused{
-fx-background-color: red; }
```